# Evaluating expressions with numerical shorthands

Tags: code-golf

You work for a company that wants to make a user-friendly calculator, and thus you have been tasked with adding the ability for users to use "numerical shorthands," that is, letters that represent numerical values, such as `k` for `1000`. Because your company wants to save money on storage in said calculators, you must minimize your code as much as possible to reduce the cost of storage.

---

### Your Task

You are to create a function that either reads an expression as input from STDIN or takes it as a parameter and returns its evaluation or prints it to STDOUT.

### Some Clarification

Let me do some definitions. First off, we have the input, which I call an expression. This can be something like the following:

```
x + y / z
```

Within this expression we have three numbers: `x`, `y`, and `z`, separated by operators (`+` and `/`). These numbers are not necessarily positive integers (or even integers). What complicates things is when we have to evaluate shorthands contained within numbers. For example, with

```
2k15
```

for purposes of evaluation, we split this up into three numbers: `2`, `1000` (which is `k`), and `15`. Then, according to the rules, we combine them to obtain

```
2*1000 + 15 = 2015
```

Hopefully this makes it a bit easier to understand the following rules.

### Rules

N.B. Unless specified otherwise, you can interpret the word "numbers" or its synonyms to include shorthands.

1. The following constitutes the numerical shorthands your function must be able to process: `k, m, b, t, and e`. `k, m, b, and t` correspond to the values `1000, 1000000, 1000000000, and 1000000000000` respectively (one thousand, one million, one billion, and one trillion). The `e` shorthand will always be followed by another number, `n`, and represents `10^n`. You must allow for numerical shorthands to be present in `n` and present before `e`. For example, `kek` evaluates to `1000*10^1000`.
2. For simplicity's sake, if a number has the shorthand `e` in it, it will only be used once.
3. Any number (*shorthands included*) before a shorthand is multiplied by it. e.g. `120kk` would be evaluated as `120 * 1000 * 1000`. If there is no number before it, you must assume that the number is 1 (like how you might, in mathematics, treat a variable `x` implicitly as `1x`). e.g. `e10` evaluates to `10^10`. Another example: `2m2k` evaluates to `2*1000000*2*1000` (nothing is added to it).
4. Any number (shorthands do not apply) following the **last shorthand** in a number containing a shorthand is added to it. e.g. `2k12` would be evaluated as `2*1000 + 12`. The exception to this is if the shorthand `e` is used, in which case the number (*shorthands included*) following `e` will be treated as `n` and evaluated as `10^n` (see the first rule).
5. Your function must be able to process the operators `+, -, *, and /` which are addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division respectively. It may process more, if you so desire.
6. Operations are evaluated according to the [order of operations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)
7. Numbers in shorthands are not only integers. `3.5b1.2` is valid and is to be evaluated as `3.5*1000000000 + 1.2 = 3500000001.2`
8. Built-ins are not allowed, if they exist for this sort of thing. The exception that I'll add would be if your language automatically converts large numbers to scientific notation, in which case that is admissible for your output.
9. Shortest code in bytes wins, standard loopholes applying.

### Input

The input will be an expression with each number and operator separated by spaces. Numbers may or may not contain a shorthand. A sample is shown below:

```
10 + 1b - 2k
```

### Output

Your function must output the evaluation of the expression as a number. It is admissible to use scientific notation if the output would be too large to display. You must have at least three decimal places if the number is not an integer. It is admissible if you retain these decimal places if the number is an integer.

### Test Cases

Input

```
t
```

Output

```
1000000000000
```

---

Input

```
1 + 4b / 10k11
```

Output

```
399561.483
```

---

Input

```
e2 + k2ke-1 - b12
```

Output

```
-999799912
```

or

```
-999799912.000
```

---

Input

```
142ek12
```

Output

```
142e1012
```

or

```
142.000e1012
```

---

Input:

```
1.2m5.25
```

Output:

```
1200005.25
```

### Final Notes

This is my first challenge posted (with some help from users on the sandbox). If anything is unclear, make it known to me and I will do my best to clarify.

Comment: Good first challenge

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks a lot! I look forward to seeing the answers.

Comment: I don't understand the second example. I thought the middle term was interpreted as `1000 + 2000 * 10 ^ -1`, but that gave a final answer of `-999998712`. (Also, my interpretation doesn't seem to jive with rule 4's "**last shorthand**," but I'm not sure how else to understand the sequence `k2k`.) Can you please explain the steps in evaluating it?

Comment: @trichoplax yes, it should only be a number; good catch.

Comment: @DLosc Of course, for that term the way you'd evaluate it would be as `1000 * 2 * 1000 * 10^-1` (see rule 3). Basically, anything that isn't after the last shorthand is multiplied together. That whole input evaluates to `100 + 1000*2*1000*10^-1 - 1000000012`.

Comment: Okay. That's not clear to me from the wording of rule 3: "Any number *before a shorthand*"--the first `k` there isn't before a shorthand, it's before the number `2`. (And it isn't a number either, unless "shorthand" is a subset of "number.") Maybe rewording rule 3 to read more like your comment above would help.

Comment: Or, disallowing cases like `k2k`, since that's equivalent to `2kk` anyway.

Comment: How should `2e3k` be interpreted? Is that `2e3000` or is it `2e3 * 1000`?

Comment: @Timwi 2e3000, judging from the last example.  `e` appears to have lowest precedence within each (compound) number.

Comment: @Timwi it would be the former (`2e3000`), see rule 1 for clarification. @DLosc you're right, I've reworded it to hopefully reduce further confusion and tried to specify that "number" includes "shorthand" where applicable.

Comment: After looking at the comments on the sandbox post, I think an example like `2m2k` should be added to the discussion of rule 3. Also, it might be best to use a different term--maybe "integer"--for the literal numbers  like `123` that are **not** shorthands. The word "number" has about 3 different definitions here, as it stands now.

Comment: Doesn't the second test case `e2 + k2ke-1 - b12` break rule 2?

Comment: @meandmycat when I say "number," (which appears to be the source of most of the confusion here -- I'll try and think of a way to make things a bit clearer), I mean each individual term that is part of the expression as a whole. `a + b`, for example, contains two numbers `a` and `b`. What complicates things is when you have shorthands within a number, since we then have to split said number up: `2k`, for example, we evaluate as if it contained two numbers being multiplied by each other (`2*1000`).

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 553 bytes

```
import sys
a=lambda i:lambda j:j*10**i
d={'k':a(3),'m':a(6),'b':a(9),'t':a(12)}
e='e'
o={'+':lambda i,j:i+j,'-':lambda i,j:i-j,'*':lambda i,j:i*j,'/':lambda i,j:i/j,e:lambda i,j:i*10**j}
r=[e,'*','/','+','-']
x=0
y=k=b=''
z=[]
q=lambda i,j:float(i or j)
for l in ''.join(sys.argv[1:]):
 if l in d:x,y=d[l](q(x,1)*q(y,1)),b
 elif l==e:z.extend([q(x+q(y,0),1),l]);x,y=0,b
 elif k==e:y+=l
 elif l in o:z.extend([x+q(y,0),l]);x,y=0,b
 else:y+=l
 k=l
z.append(x+q(y,0))
for m in r:
 while m in z:n=z.index(m);z[n-1:n+2]=[o[m](z[n-1],z[n+1])]
print repr(z[0])
```

This question looked a little unloved and seemed fun, so I gave it a shot. I've never done code golf before, so there's probably a lot that can be improved, but I gave it my best based on my knowledge of the language. An equivalent solution is possible in Python 3 at the cost of one extra byte: `print repr(z[0])` -> `print(repr(z[0]))`.

Usage is something along the lines of

```
python2 ShorthandMath.py <equation>
```

i.e.

```
python2 ShorthandMath.py e2 + k2ke-1 - b12
```

outputs

```
-999799912.0
```

Input for how to improve this would be much appreciated. If there is sufficient interest, I can ungolf and comment the program, but most of it pretty legible already (a concerning fact in code golf).

It should be noted that the program breaks with the example `142ek12` because that value is ludicrously large and the program overflows.

To compensate, the following is slightly longer, but can theoretically handle anything thrown at it due to use of the built in arbitrary precision library. Syntax is identical.

## Python 2, <s>589</s> 588 bytes (arbitrary precision)

```
import sys
from decimal import*
a=lambda i:lambda j:j*10**i
d={'k':a(3),'m':a(6),'b':a(9),'t':a(12)}
e='e'
o={'+':lambda i,j:i+j,'-':lambda i,j:i-j,'*':lambda i,j:i*j,'/':lambda i,j:i/j,e:lambda i,j:i*10**j}
r=[e,'*','/','+','-']
x=c=Decimal(0)
y=k=b=''
z=[]
q=lambda i,j:Decimal(float(i or j))
for l in ''.join(sys.argv[1:]):
 if l in d:x,y=d[l](q(x,1)*q(y,1)),b
 elif l==e:z.extend([q(x+q(y,0),1),l]);x,y=c,b
 elif k==e:y+=l
 elif l in o:z.extend([x+q(y,0),l]);x,y=c,b
 else:y+=l
 k=l
z.append(x+q(y,0))
for m in r:
 while m in z:n=z.index(m);z[n-1:n+2]=[o[m](z[n-1],z[n+1])]
print z[0]
```

Comment: I'm going to say the first version should be fine and I'll get back to you if try there's anything wrong (I can't look/think too carefully right now).

Comment: @Cole Awesome, thanks. I tried it out on every example given, and it gets all of those right at least.